# Slicing every nth range within a list with a for and a while loop

Tags: python, iteration, slice

So I have a short list called **someList** with some numbers in it. What I want to do is output every 3 elements of the list while iterating over it every 3rd slice range.

So if I have

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

The output of my **someList** should be like this

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Here is my code where I have defined a new **temp** list to store the output values

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lookupRange = 3
temp = []
for index,i in enumerate(someList):
    while index <= len(someList):
        temp.append(someList[index:index+lookupRange])
        index += 1            

print(temp)
```

However upon running this code I get some rather unexpected results...

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [7, 8, 9, 10], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [8, 9, 10], [9, 10], [10], [], [9, 10], [10], [], [10], []]
```

As you can see, for the first few lines, I do indeed get the desired output with slice range period of 3. But after that it just goes crazy...

Any ideas on whats going wrong here?

PS:I know there are probably simpler one liner ways to do this (such as the numpy.convolve function), but this problem in particular requires I do it with just for and while loops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have nested loops, but you only need one loop.

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lookupRange = 3
temp = []
for index in range(len(someList) - lookupRange + 1):
    temp.append(someList[index:index+lookupRange])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure Python one-liner; Numpy isn't required.

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lookupRange = 3
temp = list(zip(*(someList[i:] for i in range(lookupRange))))
print(temp)
```

**output**

```
[(1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 5), (4, 5, 6), (5, 6, 7), (6, 7, 8), (7, 8, 9), (8, 9, 10)]
```

In Python 2, the assignment to `temp` can be simplified to

```
temp = zip(*(someList[i:] for i in range(lookupRange)))
```

If you *really* need a list of lists instead of a list of tuples, you can change it to

```
temp = [list(u) for u in zip(*(someList[i:] for i in range(lookupRange)))]
```

which works equally well in Python 2 or 3.

But I'd stick with the tuples (unless you need to mutate those inner lists): tuples use less RAM, and code that uses tuples is often faster than the equivalent list-based code.

---

Here's that last version done with a couple of traditional `for` loops instead of a generator expression nested inside a list comprehension.

```
someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
lookupRange = 3

offset_lists = []
for i in range(lookupRange):
    offset_lists.append(someList[i:])

temp = []
for u in zip(*offset_lists):
    temp.append(list(u))
print(temp)
```

**output**

```
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension:

```
>>> someList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> chunk = 3
>>> [someList[i : i + chunk] for i in range(len(someList) - chunk + 1)]
[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [8, 9, 10]]
```